# Powershell: Create a Hashtable that automatically add keys and count up on the Value

Tags: powershell, smtp, hashtable

First off all, since this is my first question here i hope i dont mess this up. This is the first time I'm working with Powershell so im pretty lost.

I got a log file that looks something similiar to this.

```
 30.11.2020 05:05:39   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.255.255) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:39   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.254.254) disconnected. 2 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:39   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.255.255) disconnected. 4 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:39   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.234.245) disconnected. 4 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:40   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.253.244) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:41   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.255.255) disconnected. 46 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:41   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.234.245) disconnected. 13 message[s] received
```

So my goal would be, to create the hastable `$SMTP` which automatically sets the key as the IP (there are several different in the log file) and then count the value up for each message recieved.

I think I now understood the basic of a hashtable and how to manually set each keys and values, but I'm sure there must be a way to do this automatically.

I would appreciate every kind of help at this point I have no idea how to continue.

Sincerely Trippin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `-match` regex comparison operator to capture the IP address and message count from each line:

```
# Create hashtable
$SMTP = @{}

# Iterate over log lines
Get-Content path\to\file.log |ForEach-Object {
  if($_ -match '\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected. (\d+) message\[s\]'){
    # extract captured substrings
    $IP = $matches[1]
    $msgCount = $matches[2] -as [int]

    # update hashtable
    $SMTP[$IP] += $msgCount
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer this already helps me a lot, but i dont get any results could it be that there is a problem with the regex, i tried changing it in regexr to \(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\) disconnected. (\d+) message\[s\] but i also didnt got results there

Comment: Thank you very much now i get results and there are ips as keys and the amount as value. Strangely i also have several keys which are just numbers like 6, 34, 8, 19 they dont have any value, do you have an idea why they show up?

Comment: @Trippin no idea, but it sounds very odd - did you run the last part of the updated code without re-creating `$SMTP`?